# Python websocket-client WebSocketApp proxy not connecting?

Tags: python, proxy, websocket

I'm trying to use proxies with a python WebSocketApp included in the websocket module. However, whenever I use this code,

```
ws=websocket.WebSocketApp('ws://echo.websocket.org:443')
ws.run_forever(http_proxy_host='my proxy here',http_proxy_port=80, # 80 is the proxy port
    on_close=on_close)
```

I get this in the console, and then the socket closes

```
Connecting proxy...
--- request header ---
CONNECT echo.websocket.org:443 HTTP/1.0




-----------------------
--- response header ---
## SOCKET CLOSED ##
```

Help please?

Answer (score 5):

If you want a secure connection use a scheme of `wss` instead of `ws` in the URI. The default port is 443, so specifying the port is optional. Try this:

```
websocket.enableTrace(True)
ws=websocket.WebSocketApp('wss://echo.websocket.org')    # N.B. use secure socket
ws.run_forever(http_proxy_host='my proxy here', http_proxy_port=80, on_close=on_close)
```

The reason that it was failing is that the remote server is closing the connection because you were connecting on a secure port on the server, but not using a secure connection on the client.